# When using docker-compose, EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cdk

When running the following command inside a bash terminal:

```
sudo docker-compose -f "docker-compose-infra.yml" run cdk
```

This error results:

```
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

For some context the `docker-compose-infra.yml` file is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  cdk:
    command: bash -c "cdk deploy --require-approval never --all --parameters service-${ENVIRONMENT}-service:ServiceImageTag=${IMAGE_TAG}"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.infra
    environment:
      - AWS_PROFILE=${AWS_PROFILE}
      - ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
      - DEPLOY_ACCOUNT=${DEPLOY_ACCOUNT}
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials
```

Additional information:

running `sudo cdk synth -vvv` alone yields:

```
[18:12:57] CDK toolkit version: 2.61.1 (build d319d9c)
[18:12:57] Command line arguments: {
  _: [ 'synth' ],
  v: 3,
  verbose: 3,
  lookups: true,
  'ignore-errors': false,
  ignoreErrors: false,
  json: false,
  j: false,
  debug: false,
  ec2creds: undefined,
  i: undefined,
  'version-reporting': undefined,
  versionReporting: undefined,
  'path-metadata': true,
  pathMetadata: true,
  'asset-metadata': true,
  assetMetadata: true,
  'role-arn': undefined,
  r: undefined,
  roleArn: undefined,
  staging: true,
  'no-color': false,
  noColor: false,
  ci: false,
  validation: true,
  quiet: false,
  q: false,
  '$0': '/usr/local/bin/cdk'
}
[18:12:57] cdk.json: {
  "app": "python3 app.py",
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId": true,
    "aws-cdk:enableDiffNoFail": "true",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021": true
  }
}
[18:12:57] cdk.context.json: {
  "availability-zones:account=xxxxxxxx:region=eu-west-1": [
    "eu-west-1a",
    "eu-west-1b",
    "eu-west-1c"
  ],
  "endpoint-service-availability-zones:account=xxxxxxxxx:region=eu-west-1:serviceName=com.amazonaws.vpce.eu-west-1.vpce-svc-xxxxxxxx": [
    "eu-west-1a",
    "eu-west-1b"
  ]
}
[18:12:57] merged settings: {
  versionReporting: true,
  pathMetadata: true,
  output: 'cdk.out',
  app: 'python3 app.py',
  context: {
    '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId': true,
    'aws-cdk:enableDiffNoFail': 'true',
    '@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier': true,
    '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021': true
  },
  debug: false,
  assetMetadata: true,
  toolkitBucket: {},
  staging: true,
  bundlingStacks: [ '**' ],
  lookups: true
}
[18:12:57] [trace] SdkProvider#withAwsCliCompatibleDefaults()
[18:12:57] Determining if we're on an EC2 instance.
[18:12:57] Does not look like an EC2 instance.
[18:12:57] Reading cached notices from /root/.cdk/cache/notices.json
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
[18:12:57] Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Comment: Does running it without docker-compose work?

Comment: No, I have added the output from `sudo cdk synth -vvv`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this error arises because `~/.aws/credentials` was a directory and not a file. My use case is `aws sso login`, so I just deleted the `~/.aws/credentials` directory and this solved the problem.